# Split PDF into documents with several pages each

Tags: scripting, pdf, split

There are several resources on the web explaining how one can split a PDF into many files with on page per file.

But how can you split them into chunks of, say, five pages each? I have looked into the standard tools such as `pdftk` but could not find an option doing what I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pdftk` is able to cut out a fixed set of pages efficiently. With a bit of scripting glue, this does what I want:

```
number=$(pdfinfo -- "$file" 2> /dev/null | awk '$1 == "Pages:" {print $2}')
count=$((number / pagesper))
filename=${file%.pdf}

counter=0
while [ "$count" -gt "$counter" ]; do 
  start=$((counter*pagesper + 1));
  end=$((start + pagesper - 1));

  counterstring=$(printf %04d "$counter")
  pdftk "$file" cat "${start}-${end}" output "${filename}_${counterstring}.pdf"

  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

This assumes that you have the number of pages per chunk in `$pagesper` and the filename of the source PDF in `$file`.

If you have `acroread` installed, you can also use

```
acroread -size a4 -start "$start" -end "$end" -pairs "$file" "${filename}_${counterstring}.ps"
```

`acroread` offers the option `-toPostScript` which may be useful.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/akerbos/scripts/blob/master/pdfsplitk) for a more complete implementation.

Answer (score 10):

See also `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` from [`poppler-utils`](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/). `pdfseparate` breaks the file into one file per page which makes it relatively easy to reassemble at will later on with `pdfunite`, manually or (semi-)automatically.

Like with zsh:

```
autoload zargs

reunite() pdfunite "$@" file-$1-$argv[-1].pdf

pdfseparate file.pdf p%d
zargs -n 5 p<->(n) -- reunite
rm -f p<->
```

would split `file.pdf` into `file-p1-p5.pdf`, `file-p6-p10.pdf`...

Comment: Nice. It creates lots of temporary files, though.

Comment: This script worked perfectly with me, after realizing that I should add `#!/bin/zsh` as a first line. And installing Z Shell, of course... Those details might not be obvious to beginners.

Answer (score 3):

I find Python with the [PyPdf library](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) convenient for those jobs that pdftk doesn't do conveniently (or at all).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# Command line parsing
if len(sys.argv) < 2 or sys.argv[1][-4:] != '.pdf':
    sys.stderr.writeln('Usage: ' + sys.argv[0] + ''' FILE.pdf N
Split FILE.pdf into chunks of N pages each.''')
    exit(3)
pages_per_file = int(sys.argv[2])

base_name = sys.argv[1][:-4] + '-'
input_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(sys.argv[1]))
output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
num_pages = input_pdf.getNumPages()
for i in xrange(num_pages):
    output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))
    if (i + 1) % pages_per_file == 0 or i + 1 == num_pages:
        output_file = open(base_name + str(i / pages_per_file + 1) + '.pdf', "wb")
        output_pdf.write(output_file)
        output_file.close()
        output_pdf = PdfFileWriter()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:

    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./dividePDF.py", line 23, in <module>
         if (i + 1) % pages_per_file == 0: flush()
      File "./dividePDF.py", line 18, in flush
        output_pdf.write(output_file)
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output_pdf' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Before that, I was getting this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dividePDF.py", line 20, in <module>
    for i in xrange(input_pdf.getNumPages(input_pdf)):
TypeError: getNumPages() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

So I changed `input_pdf.getNumPages(input_pdf)` to `input_pdf.getNumPages()` and got the other error.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Thanks for the bug report, I fixed the script.

Comment: I just used this script with N=4, but the first "chunk" always had 3 pages instead of 4. The following chunks were OK. I changed the order of lines     "if (i + 1) % pages_per_file == 0: flush()" and "output_pdf.addPage(input_pdf.getPage(i))" and it worked right.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro Thanks again, I fixed that in a slightly different way and fixed a bug when the last file is shorter because the number of pages is not a multiple of the chunk size.

Comment: Isn't pyPdf available in Ubuntu 18.04 anymore?

Comment: @LeonardoCastro No, it's been replaced by pyPDF2 which is similar but not fully compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by Raphael is flawed: if you have an uneven number of pages, the last ones are just ignored. There it is an improved solution that works also with an uneven number of pages.
Again, assumes that you have the number of pages per chunk in `$pagesper` and the filename of the source PDF in `$file`.

```
number=$(pdfinfo -- "$file" 2> /dev/null | awk '$1 == "Pages:" {print $2}')

count=$((($number+$pagesper-1)/$pagesper))
filename=${file%.pdf}

counter=0
while [ "$count" -gt "$counter" ]; do
  start=$((counter*pagesper + 1));
  end=$((start + pagesper - 1));
  if [ $end -gt $number ]; then
    end=$number
  fi

  counterstring=$(printf %04d "$counter")
  pdftk "$file" cat "${start}-${end}" output "${filename}_${counterstring}.pdf"
  counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Comment: Good catch, thanks! You could just have edited that into my answer, though.

Comment: Oh sorry, I tought I couldn't edit someone else answer with low reputation.

Comment: You can, kind of; the edit will be reviewed by high-reps. Given that you fixed an actual bug, I assume they would have accepted it! (You get +2 rep for accepted edits, too.)