# How many pages has pdf? (count in bash script)

Tags: shell-script, pdf

How many pages has pdf?

Could you provide a way to get this information in bash script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my `pdfpages` script. The machines I use tend to have at least one of [QPDF](https://qpdf.sourceforge.io/) (`qpdf`) or [Poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (`pdfinfo`) so it's good enough for me, but there are other tools that can do the job.

```
#! /bin/sh
if type qpdf >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  pdfpages1 () {
    qpdf --show-npages "$1"
  }
elif type pdfinfo >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  pdfpages1 () {
    pdfinfo -- "$1" | sed -n '/^Pages:/ s/.*[^0-9]//p'
  }
else
  echo 1>&2 "None of the supported tools is available: pdfinfo, qpdf"
fi
for x; do
  printf '%8d %s\n' $(pdfpages1 "$x") "$x"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function how_many_pages_pdf() { pdfinfo -- "$1" 2> /dev/null | awk '$1 == "Pages:" {print $2}' ; }

pdffile=article.pdf
n="$( how_many_pages_pdf "$pdffile" )"

echo $n
```

based on : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66932